# Admin user always prehend initial user

Tags: inno-setup

Using an InnoSetup script (that seems to work fine under XP/Vista), i've a strange behavior under Seven RC:

here is the [Files] section:

```
[Files]
Source: *.ico; DestDir: {app}\bin; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: dist\*.*; DestDir: {app}\bin; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: catalog\*.*; DestDir: {userappdata}\JetWorksheet\catalog; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: wizards\*.*; DestDir: {userappdata}\JetWorksheet\wizards; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: images\*.*; DestDir: {userdocs}\JetWorksheet\images; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: wordlists\*.*; DestDir: {userdocs}\JetWorksheet\wordlists; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

The problem is:

In place of using the {userappdata} of the user that started the setup, all the data goes to the "Admin" directories...

I'm surely missing somethings...

Answer (score 2):

You should either use PrivilegesRequired=lowest so your Setup doesnt elevate, or you should place the default user files in a common directory during installation, and then have your application copy them to the user area on startup.